# I want to send a "mixed", chunked response of JSON and a string with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, chunking

I'm working on a ChatGPT integration in Node/Express and would like to first respond to my client with some metadata in JSON, then start streaming ChatGPT's response as it streams in.

Currently, there are no errors and it works but the chunks are coming through in an unexpected manner on the client side.  The client onprogress handler doesn't start receiving chunks until the server starts sending the chunked response from GPT.

Server-Side

```
// Send response message array to client
res.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked')
let chunkedJSON = chunkString(JSON.stringify(myJSON), 20)
for(let i = 0; i < chunkedJSON.length; i++){
  res.write(chunkedJSON[i])
}
res.write('END-JSON')

// Get GPT Response
const stream = await openai.chat.completions.create(
  {
    messages: messages,
    model: thread.model,
    stream: true
  },
  {
    responseType: "stream"
  }
)

// Stream ChatGPT response
for await (const part of stream) {
  tokens++ // each chunk from the completion API is a token
  if (part.choices[0].finish_reason === "stop") {
    res.end();
  } else {
    res.write(part.choices[0]?.delta?.content || "")
  }
}
```

Client-Side

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", environment.serverBaseUrl + '/chat/message', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("x-access-token", this.userAuth!);
xhr.onprogress = function () {
  var curr_index = xhr.responseText.length;
  if (last_index == curr_index) return; 
  var s = xhr.responseText.substring(last_index, curr_index);
  last_index = curr_index;
  console.log("PROGRESS:", s);
}
xhr.onload = function () {
  console.log("COMPLETE:", xhr.responseText);
}
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
  test: true,
  message: message
}));
```

Comment: You can generally only send one kind of response. Maybe you can use two separate requests, one for the JSON and then a second one for the streamed response.

Answer (score 0):

Removing res.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked') worked